# How to show alert in iOS application from bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ibeacon

Is possible show an alert or a push local notification on iphone device then click in a bluetooth button device?

So is possible do this when app is on background and is correct do this with Beacon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes. Just make your Bluetooth protocol and set an identifier for this action.(Get this action in Bluetooth delegate)
2.No. iBeacon is specified for fixed information, for example, ID, major. You can only find an iBeacon device and get information. But you can't communicate with it by the **iBeacon** protocol. However, if you can design the iBeacon device, you can communicate by the **Bluetooth** protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But without use iBeacon, using normally CoreBluetooth is possible in background app send by clicking like a push local notification?

Comment: @user3745888 It's not possible when your app was terminated.

Comment: but.. when is only background without kill ths? not posiible? like applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: @user3745888 You can send local notification.

Comment: oh! thanks, nice. If I can use local notification it's amazing, there is some question related to see an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and very simple.   Many manufacturers make "click-on" beacons like Radius Network's [Dot](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-dot) model.  When clicked, the beacon transmits its unique identifiers, and iOS Core Location APIs will wake your app up -- even if killed or it has not been launched since boot -- and deliver a `didEnter(region: CLRegion)` callback.  You can send a local notification to

As noted by @Lumialxk, an iBeacon only sends numeric identifiers, so you need to translate between those identifiers and a message to be displayed to the user in your app.  This is often done with a simple if statement or a lookup table.

Once you have this message, you can present it to the user as a local notification like so:

```
  let notificationMessage = "Beacon button clicked"
  let notification = UILocalNotification()
  notification.alertBody = notificationMessage
  notification.alertAction = "OK"
  UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
```

Full Disclosure:  I work for Radius Networks.

Comment: and is possible use a bluetooth podshutter or other 4.0 ble device instead of iBeacon to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can only launch an app on Bluetooth detection using iBeacon, because Apple has integrated it with CoteLocation that has that ability.  Other Bluetooth devices can do this in a timely manner only when the app is on the foreground, after a delay (or not at all depending on the Bluetooth advertising/connection type) in the background, and not at all when the app is killed or not launched since boot.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the answer! but I'm reading about BLE Background advertisement and custom advertisement data like a local notification.. so this local notification are possible with any bluetooth podshutter or other? because don't say nothing of iBeacon..

Comment: There may be many different ways Podshutters are implemented.

Comment: How Podshutters work is a very different question.  I'd suggest posting that as a new question if you want to get an answer.  Since implementations may vary, it may help to reference a specific vendor and model.

Comment: Really thanks!! I have a new question, not exactly with Podsshutter, but with a keychain. How to show local notification when find bluetooth device in background in iOS? is my question published, I would appreciate it if you could help me with your experience.